# Are these two statements correct?( Sum of convergence and divergent series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Question link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m55Pb.png)

Need with these two statements. Are they true or false?. For me, I feel that statement A is correct while statement B is wrong. Is it correct? I have inserted the link of the image

For statement B=
If Uk is k and Vk is -k, the limit of the Uk is infinity and divergent, the limit of Vk is also infinity and divergent but when you add them together, which is sigma(Uk + Vk)=sigma(k+(-k)), the answer is 0 and converges

Not too sure about A

Comment: Please show what you have done.

Comment: Can you come up with a proof of statement A and a counter-example for statement B ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy edited

Comment: @Theleb edited it

Answer (score 1):

Statement A is True .

Statement B is false.
Explanation:

Statement A
Let, if possible
Partial sum sequence of (an+bn) converges
Since, series an is cgt => partial sum sequence of an is also cgt.
From Algebra of sequences, we can say, partial sum sequence of (an+bn-an) is also cgt .=> Partial sum sequence of bn is cgt . Contradiction arises.
Hence, series (an+bn) must be divergent.

Statement B :
Your example is perfect counter.
if an ={n n€N} & bn ={ -n : n€N}
Then both series divergent but their sum - series converges.